# Ajax Max Redirect

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to run a script that imports information based on a large data source. To make sure it doesn't timeout (i can't use settimelimit), i end up doing a redirect to the same page with different parameters to continue import at a certain point in time.

To make this script work with a cronjob, i was able to call:

```
wget 
    --max-redirect=10000
    --no-check-certificate
    --delete-after
    http://www.xyz.com/admin/update_products.php?key=abc
```

This allowed me to do the complete script easily... Problem, i now need to make this triggerable by the user. Thus i automaticaly thought of jQuery.ajax() to fix my issue. Problem is, jQuery.ajax() stops processing redirects after 20 redirects, just like my browser.

So i'm wondering, is it my browser not accepting the redirect past the 20 limit or is it a standard between all protocols to stop at 20 redirect.

Can i configure the AJAX request to actually go more than 20 requests or will i have to change my script to support both scenarios, one with cronjob that requires auto redirect and one with a url response that tells ajax to go "there" next!

Thankx